# Почему не срабатывает change, во второй раз?

Tags: javascript

на кнопке висит `change`:

```
<input type="file" id="inp" />

$('#inp').change(function(e) {
    alert('a');
});
```

пользователь нажал, выбрал файл в диалоге, и подтвердил

alert сработал

пользователь нажал, выбрал тот же файл, подтвердил

alert не сработал

почему система не вызывает событие во второй раз?

Comment: может зависеть от браузера. Браузер может проверить что выбранный файл не изменился, следовательно нет смысла выкидывать событие изменения

Comment: @Grundy, это логично, сам пришел к такому же мнению. Но клиенты жалуются. Значит средствами браузера это точно не решается?

Comment: может есть еще какое-нибудь событие по которому можно отлавливать дубликаты и сообщать от этом пользователю?

Comment: а что происходит по событию? какой смысл повторять это действие, если выбран **тот же самый** файл?

Comment: @Grundy, может есть промежуточные события, типа start-finish-cancel можно было бы на их основе смоделировать ситуацию с дубликатом ИМХО

Comment: Нет, это просто **не нужно**

Answer (score 3):

так заработало:

```js
$('#inp').change(function(e) {
    alert('a');
    $('#inp').val(null);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="inp" />
```

Comment: хм, а какой в этом смысл?

Comment: @Igor, см. мой ответ.

Comment: Ахахах. А смысл какой, если выбранный файл обнуляется для выборки?

Comment: @Igor, это актуально если обработка выбранного файла производится без обновления страницы. Файл можно отправить на сервер через ajax или сокеты. А можно вставить на canvas.

Answer (score 2):

Второй раз `change` не срабатывает, поскольку ты выбираешь тот же самый файл. Т. е. изменение как бы и не произошло. Если выбрать другой файл, то всё сработает.

Если действительно нужна обработка выбора того же файла, можно сбрасывать значение input'а - в таком случае оно каждый раз будет меняться на выбранный файл.